# Button Click Animation

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications, button

I'm developing a WebApp for Android, so I've added a custom button like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="btRegister" onClick="register()">
    Register
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#btRegister {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px -1px 1px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-width: 0 8px 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-image: url('shared/btRegister.png') 0 8 0 8;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The problem is that when the user clicks the custom button there is no sensation that the button was clicked(it executes the `register()` code without problems), so I've designed another button background called `btRegister_Clicked.png`, so I want to know how I can make some way that when the user clicks the button that image gets changed to the `_clicked` one and then go back to the normal one, just like a normal button does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<div id="btRegister" onClick="clickButton(this); register();">
    Register
</div>

function clickButton(btn){
    //change image
    setTimeout(function(){
        //change image back
    }, 120);
}
```

---

Not very sure about this but you might also try using an `<a>` element instead. This way you might be able to style the buttons with [`pseudo-classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-classes) and avoid having to handle the changing of the button in JavaScript. In particular, the [`:active` psuedo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) seem like it would be perfect for this use case. However, note that with Mobile Safari at least, [it doesn't work without a little extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari).

```
#btRegister{
    /*normal style*/
}

#btRegister:active{
    /*style when active - change background image*/
}

<a id="btRegister" href="#" onClick="register()" ontouchstart="">Register</a>
<!--ontouchstart="" is a fix for Mobile Safari -->
```

Comment: How would this be using the `pseudo-classes`, since I can't see any `click` class...

Comment: @Nathan Well, [`:active`](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-19.html#foo) would be perfect, but with Mobile Safari it doesn't seem to work as expected by itself, but there's an [easy fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari) - I don't have an Android device at hand, so I can't say for sure but since both browsers are WebKit based, this should work.

Comment: @Nathan Updated my answer. And I can't find anything that seems to suggest that `:active` doesn't work with Android. Also note that some browsers support `:active` for any DOM element, not just links.

Answer (score 0):

To create html buttons with states use kodeinfo's editor . It defines normal , hovered and pressed state so just make changes using interface and download the html code . you can do more than just creating states you can use gradients , borders , text formatting , icons etc