# CSS pseudo class for when a user is touching an element in iOS Safari?

Tags: iphone, css, ios, css-selectors, pseudo-class

In Safari on iOS, is there a CSS pseudo class for when a user is touching an element? Or do I have to use javascript?

Similar to how :hover works on desktop computers, it would be active while the finger is touching the element, and then be inactive as soon as the user stops touching the element.

Answer (score 2):

CSS currently does not define any user-action pseudo-classes for touch paradigms.

You'll have to listen for events and handle them accordingly with JavaScript. In fact, Apple recommends this; see [Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) in the Safari Web Content Guide for details. You'll want to look at the `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove` and `touchcancel` events, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877902/520129

> ```html
> <body ontouchstart="">
>     ...
> </body>
> ```
>
> Applied just once, as opposed to every button element seemed to fix
>   all buttons on the page. Alternatively you could use this small JS
>   library called '[Fastclick][1]'. It speed up click events on touch
>   devices and takes care of this issue too.
>
> [1]:
>   http://assanka.net/content/tech/2011/08/26/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/

Comment: I'm confused. How does this answer the question given here? You also appear to have quoted the link markdown incorrectly - that [1]: URL shouldn't be in the quote.

Comment: Adding ontouchstart="" on your body tag will make :active pseudo class work on ios/android on touchdown.