# How do I implement HOVER effect in mobile

Tags: css, hover

This is the page `http://www.arctic15.com/speakers/`
When you hover on a speaker photo, it reveals his/her information. But how do I implement this in mobile?
I want when a speaker comes in focus on mobile screen it should automatically reveals info.

Comment: the concept hover do not exist in the mobile environment...You need to use the touch.

Comment: How exactly does one hover in a mobile environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <body ontouchstart="">
       ...
    </body>
```

Applied just once, as opposed to every button element seemed to fix all buttons on the page. Alternatively you could use this small JS library called 'Fastclick'. It speed up click events on touch devices and takes care of this issue too.

[:active pseudo-class doesn't work in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)