# Does tapping an <a> tag with an iPad trigger CSS :focus status?

Tags: css, ipad, focus

I have a dropdown which uses CSS `a#hoverlink:hover+div` to make a div to appear, then you can click a link in the div.

On Android, when you click the hoverlink, it triggers `:hover` so this works fine.

I heard this isn't working in an iPad. How can I make it work? I'm thinking using `:focus` as an alternative to `:hover` would do the job. Will clicking trigger `:focus` in iPad safari?

I would just test it, but I don't have an iPad to try it with:

```css
a#hoverlink+div { transition: all 2s; }
a#hoverlink:not(:focus)+div { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:" id="hoverlink">the link</a><div> yes! focus worked, now wondering if click works<br/><a href="javascript:" onclick="alert('great, it worked!')">click here!</a></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [:active pseudo-class doesn't work in mobile safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: I'm asking about `:focus`, not :active.

Comment: George Bailey Doesn't work on my iPad (iOS 8).

Comment: Nor on a Samsung Galaxy Tab. And on a desktop computer, the text does show up but the second link doesn't produce an alert.

Comment: Android and Desktop will use `:hover` so they would work fine. Thanks for the answer about `:focus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, it sounds like the `:active` idea doesn't work.

While IMI's `:target` technique would work, in my case it would conflict with JavaScript-driven use of the hash string for other purposes.

So my answer is just to use JavaScript `onclick` to add a class which will cause the dropdown to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using :target. Below is a purely CSS example. You should be able to tweek it with Javascript to your needs.

Here is a reference for using :target
https://css-tricks.com/on-target/

```css
a#hoverlink+div { transition: all 2s; }
a#hoverlink:not(:target)+div { visibility: none; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<a href="#hoverlink" id="hoverlink">Show The Div</a>
<div>You should see this once the link is clicked</div>
```

Comment: Cool, did not know this was possible.

Comment: This method does work to create a mobile friendly css dropdown without the use of JS. I have tested it on several iOS and android devices. For a live use case you can visit http://paulrobertlloyd.com/ where he is currently using a similar :target technique for his mobile navigation. For anyone interested in the method behind his css mobile menu check out this page: http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/build-smart-mobile-navigation-without-hacks-6126265