# iphone :active pseudoclass not working in safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, safari

I have a webpage that doesn't display correctly in safari.

The :active pseudoclass (which should turn the button yellow when pressed) doesn't work.
Of course it works in any other browser.

Applied this solution, not working: 
[:active pseudo-class doesn't work in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)

Here is my example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mt4sf7ov/

```
button:focus {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
background-color: yellow;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 2px 20px;
}
```

Comment: There is no `:active` in your example.

Comment: forgot, but anyway doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/sqgnh4u1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved, solution can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/quo85do3/5/

```
button:hover{
-webkit-appearance: none;
background:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please placed Styles as below in your css file.
button:active {-webkit-appearance: none;border-radius: 0;background-color: red;font-size: 30px;padding: 2px 20px;}

Comment: still doesn't work!  https://jsfiddle.net/sqgnh4u1/   (when clicking it's yellow but when releasing the finger goes back to normal)