# Apply a style to a button when pressed using CSS only on touch devices

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style a button on touch devices using CSS only?

I know `:hover` works for adding a style, but I can't remove the style when the user presses off the button and on to the pages background.

Is there a CSS-only solution or would I need to delve into JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:focus`

```css
.btn{
  border: solid 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input
    class="btn"
    type="submit"
    value="Button"
>
```

Try

```
<body ontouchstart="">
    ...
</body>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877902/6670723)

Comment: Does not seem to work. Style is not removed when clicking off the button.

Comment: It should work I guess, that's what a `:focus` class do.

Comment: Perhaps `:focus` does not work like that on touch devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

```css
button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Don't use [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) for the pressed state. It's for selecting elements with, e.g., the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. You have to detect the touchscreen device using **@media (pointer: coarse)**.
2. Then, you should target the button for active state in combination with focus state.
3. Before applying style to your pressed button, you should define a style only for focus (if you have one/need one).

**Example:**

```
@media (pointer: coarse) {
  button:focus {
    border-color: red;
  }
  
  button:active,
  button:active:focus {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```javascript
body::after{ content: "I don't know what you are using to click" }

@media (pointer: coarse) {
  body { background: crimson }
  body::after{ content: "Your primary input mechanism is a finger" }
}

@media (pointer: fine) {
  body { background: goldenrod }
  body::after{ content: "Your primary input mechanism is a mouse" }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: What is this? [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29)?